# How to embed Automator Action in App Bundle for delivery

Tags: objective-c, macos, automator, codesign

I'm on Objective-c Xcode 11, macOS not iOS.

I have a small app in objective-c, sandboxed. To make it more accessible i added script support and therefore developed some Automator actions.

I want to embed them in the app bundle so the user doesn't need to install them seperately.

Regarding the documentation this works by placing them in the app bundle like this:

```
myapp.app/Library/Automator/actionHere
```

What i tried:

I created an archive and copied the finished product (automator action) to my app folder (in finder) and added it to the project (without copying). Then i added a copy files phase to copy it to the above folder (selected 'Wrapper' + 'Library/Automator'). I tried both with "Sign on copy" and without.

Unfortunately, signing of the app fails with "unsealed contents present in root directory" - without the automator action it builds fine.

Team ID for codesigning and certificates match for both apps.
Base identifier is the same e.g. com.mycompany.product and com.mycompany.product.automator.action1

Then i tried to embed the Automator project as subproject. But that failed at all....

How can i either add the Automator project as subproject of the main app project and get the final automator ation in the above mentioned directory OR how can i add the already codesigned Automator action to the app properly so that codesigning doesn't fail.

Regards
Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Automator action**

- Create an archive for distribution
- Codesign it with the same certificate as your main app

**Main App**

- Copy the final product to your main app (in finder) and add it to your project
- Remove it from "Copy resources" build phase
- Create new copy files phase (right after the copy resources phase), select "Resources" and enter "Library/Automator"
- Add it to the new copy files phase

**Test it**

- Create an archive of your main app
- Copy the product to the application folder (important - otherwise action won't be installed by OSX
- Open Automator, you should find your action there. If not - restart.

Comment: Important: You should click "Copy only when installing" in the copy files phase where you copy the automator workflow. Then it will only be included in an archive build. Otherwise it will be included in a debug build also. Then - for example if you sign debug builds different then archive codesign will fail (cause different certificates have been used)

Comment: there is a bit better solution + better way to test https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1885/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit better solution than [Pat_Morita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58493451/2648673)

1. Add automator action as dependency
2. Add New Copy Files phase
3. Destination change to Products Directory
4. Change subpath to `${CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH}/Library/Automator` (example Pixelmator)

For correct behaviour app bundle has to be place in /Applications

[image]