# Add another application to the Quick Action Library in Automator mac

Tags: macos, automator

I m using Mac Automator app to add new actions to the right click quick menu for files and folder. As can we seen in the image we have a number of actions available for mail app and other apps. I wanted to know whether something similar can be done for my app. I wanted to list my app in the library and provide some similar options. Can it be done?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58475697/10853463